# React Incorrect render when combine withRouter/withStyles and mobx's observer

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm building an react app with mobx. Everything was working fine with `withRouter` and `withStyles`, since I need to access the store, so I added `store` to the component as a wrapper in `observer`. But since I've done that, the rendering stopped working correctly on its child component. How should I access the store correctly?

**Edit**: Found one way to inject store in the component with `@observer`
simplified code:

```
@observer
class PersistentDrawerLeft extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: true,
    }
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
  }

  routeTo = (path) => () => {
    this.props.history.push(path)
  }

  onRoute = (route) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      if (route === '/' && window.location.hash === '#/') return true; // home route
      if (route !== '/' && window.location.hash !== '#/' && window.location.hash.indexOf(route.toLowerCase().replace('/', '')) !== -1) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open,
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar>
         
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            <IconButton onClick={this.toggle}>
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
           <ListItem button onClick={this.routeTo(routes.TOKEN)}>
              <ListItemIcon className={this.onRoute(routes.TOKEN) ? classes.active : classes.passive}><EmojiEmotionsIcon /></ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText className={this.onRoute(routes.TOKEN) ? classes.active : classes.passive} primary={"Token"} />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main
          className={clsx(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open,
          })}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
)}}
```

Wrapper:

```
const Wrapped = withRouter(withStyles(styles)(PersistentDrawerLeft));

export default function Observer () {
  const store = useStores()
  return (<Wrapped store={store} />)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `Observer` does not benefit from `observer` decorator at all, since `observer` will only rerender if some observable property change, but store itself is not observable and it will probably never change.

What you need to do is wrap `PersistentDrawerLeft` with `observer`

```
const Wrapped = withRouter(withStyles(styles)(observer(PersistentDrawerLeft)));
```